# Searching in a JSON file.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

I am trying to search the capital city of a country by using their ISO (cca2) codes.

I am doing the following:

```
 var json =   $.getJSON('Countries.json', function(data)
{
       return data;
});

var CapitalCity = getCapitalByCCA2(json, code.toString().toUpperCase());

alert(CapitalyCity);

function getCapitalByCCA2(json, code) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                if (json[i].cca2 === code.toString().toUpperCase()) {
                    return json[i].capital;
                    console.log(json[i]);
                }
            }
    return null;
};
```

Structure of JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": {
            "common": "Afghanistan",
            "official": "Islamic Republic of Afghanistan",
            "native": {
                "common": "\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646",
                "official": "\u062f \u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u064a \u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u062a"
            }
        },
        "tld": [".af"],
        "cca2": "AF",
        "ccn3": "004",
        "cca3": "AFG",
        "currency": ["AFN"],
        "callingCode": ["93"],
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "altSpellings": ["AF", "Af\u0121\u0101nist\u0101n"],
        "relevance": "0",
        "region": "Asia",
        "subregion": "Southern Asia",
        "nativeLanguage": "pus",
        "languages": {
            "prs": "Dari",
            "pus": "Pashto",
            "tuk": "Turkmen"
        },
        "translations": {
            "cym": "Affganistan",
            "deu": "Afghanistan",
            "fra": "Afghanistan",
            "hrv": "Afganistan",
            "ita": "Afghanistan",
            "jpn": "\u30a2\u30d5\u30ac\u30cb\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3",
            "nld": "Afghanistan",
            "rus": "\u0410\u0444\u0433\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d",
            "spa": "Afganist\u00e1n"
        },
        "latlng": [33, 65],
        "demonym": "Afghan",
        "borders": ["IRN", "PAK", "TKM", "UZB", "TJK", "CHN"],
        "area": 652230
    },
    {
        "name": {
            "common": "\u00c5land Islands",
            "official": "\u00c5land Islands",
            "native": {
                "common": "\u00c5land",
                "official": "Landskapet \u00c5land"
            }
        },
        "tld": [".ax"],
        "cca2": "AX",
        "ccn3": "248",
        "cca3": "ALA",
        "currency": ["EUR"],
        "callingCode": ["358"],
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "altSpellings": ["AX", "Aaland", "Aland", "Ahvenanmaa"],
        "relevance": "0",
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Northern Europe",
        "nativeLanguage": "swe",
        "languages": {
            "swe": "Swedish"
        },
        "translations": {
            "deu": "\u00c5land",
            "fra": "\u00c5land",
            "hrv": "\u00c5landski otoci",
            "ita": "Isole Aland",
            "jpn": "\u30aa\u30fc\u30e9\u30f3\u30c9\u8af8\u5cf6",
            "nld": "\u00c5landeilanden",
            "rus": "\u0410\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430",
            "spa": "Alandia"
        },
        "latlng": [60.116667, 19.9],
        "demonym": "\u00c5landish",
        "borders": [],
        "area": 1580
    }

    }

]
```

The problem is that the data is not getting fetched.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous Ajax request!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call to get the answer for the first part of your problem.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid (an extra { at the end). Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to valid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` does not work as you are expecting it to, with the data returned into a variable.  Instead what you need to do is provide a callback with `$.getJSON()` to work with the results.  Try calling your function from within the success callback.

```
// variable to store captial city
var CapitalCity;
// The country code you are filtering on
var countryCode = '...';
$.getJSON('Countries.json', function(data) {
    CapitalCity = getCapitalByCCA2(data, countryCode);      
});
```

You could actually look at the search suggestion provided by @MathieuLabrieParent and get rid of your function altogether.  I however might change to use `$.each()` for array iteration such that you can break out of the loop when you find the matching item.  That might look like this:

```
// variable to store captial city
var CapitalCity;
// The country code you are filtering on
var countryCode = code.toString().toUpperCase();
$.getJSON('Countries.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        if (element.cca2 === countryCode) {
            CapitalCity = match.capital;
            // break the loop
            return false;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @Brian  See update to my answer that was made after you accepted it.  It has better looping logic, such that you can break the loop upon match condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should use grep to filter the json like so :

```
var returnedData = $.grep(json, function (element, index) {
    return element.cca2 === code.toString().toUpperCase();
});
```

returnData will contain an array of the filtered json.

I don't see any definition of the `var code` in your code.

Comment: Problem is with the Ajax call... You missed that.

Comment: Oops ... your right. Still a good idea to filter with grep.